# Infinity of every ZF model

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic

Let's define $S(x) = x \cup \{x\}$.

1. Prove that axioms of ZF (semantically) imply that all sets $\emptyset, S(\emptyset), S(S(\emptyset)), \dots$ are pairwise distinct.
2. Prove (without axiom of infinity) that every model of ZF theory is infinite.

I don't really understand what does it mean that axioms semantically imply. I can write a formula $\Phi(x)$ that will be true for $S^{(n)}(\emptyset)$ and will be false for $S^{(m)}(\emptyset)$. Is it sufficient?

For the second part it seems that it is an implication of 1. since all models of ZF have to contain all $S^{(n)}(\emptyset)$ so our model has at least infinite subset.

Comment: I suppose "semantically" means you are allowed to refer to models instead of working directly with the axioms. (2) indeed follows from (1).

Comment: @ZhenLin what do you mean by referring to models?

Comment: So....you're asking us to prove that A semantically implies B, even though you're not sure what "semantically implies" means.  I am having a great deal of difficulty imagining the circumstance in which you'd want to know whether something is true before you know what it means.

Comment: @WillO I know what is semantics and other logical notions. But "semantic implication" is hidden knowledge from me. Probably, I should ask a question what is it in separation, but nevertheless.
Secondly, as you can see from my attempt, I'm trying to clarify my understanding.

Comment: Jihad:  To say that A semantically implies B usually means that whenever A is true, B is also true (that is, in any model where A becomes true, so does B).

Comment: Where did you get the statements (or should I say commands :-)) 1 and 2 from? (Pace WillO), "semantically imply" is not standard terminology, so some context is needed to give a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviousely in each model there are such elements as: $\emptyset = S^{(0)}(\emptyset), S(\emptyset) = S^{(1)}(\emptyset), \dots$. If we prove that they are pairwise distinct it will imply that every ZF model have to be infinite.

Let's write down some $S^{(i)}$. One can gain:

$$
\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}\}, \dots
$$

Everyone can see that if $n < m$ then $S^{(n)}(\emptyset) \in S^{(m)}(\emptyset)$. Let's prove it by induction:

1. **Base**. $S^{(n)}(\emptyset) \in S^{(n+1)}(\emptyset)$ by definition.
2. **Step**. Assume $S^{(n)}(\emptyset) \in S^{(m)}(\emptyset)$, but $S^{(m+1)}(\emptyset) = \{S^{(m)}(\emptyset), \{S^{(m)}(\emptyset)\}\}$, hence each element of $S^{(m)}(\emptyset)$ we can also find in $S^{(m+1)}(\emptyset)$, therefore in $S^{(n)}(\emptyset)$ too.

Assume the contrary. Let $\exists n, m, n < m: S^{(n)}(\emptyset) = S^{(m)}(\emptyset)$. But we proved that $S^{(n)}(\emptyset) \in S^{(m)}(\emptyset) = S^{(n)}(\emptyset)$. This contradicts axiom of regularity. *The end*.